# What is "modified frequency slice wavelet transform"?

Tags: frequency, wavelet

What is "modified frequency slice wavelet transform"? It was written in an article but It's not been described on the web.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to that article ?

Comment: It was used in a lot of article on the web if hello @Hilmar , you search it but the article which I used it, is "a new arterial fibrillation detection system with noise cancellation and signal annotation".